# Как обновить Python 3.4.4 до версии 3.4.10 в Windows XP? И Что такое "Gzipped source tarball" и "XZ compressed source tarball"?

Tags: python

Что-то у меня не получается найти установку Python 3.4.10 для Windows, хотя версия (3.4.10) как бы есть.
Ссылка: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3410/

Comment: Установщиков для 3.4.10 больше не предлагается, потому что версия версия 3.4 достигла конца жизненного цикла и больше не поддерживается (как и ХР). На вопросы "что такое" очень хорошо отвечает гугл.

Comment: Зачем такое обновление? Лучше обновитесь до например 3.8 или 3.9. (только заодно и винду обновите, если можно).A если нет — то оставьте так, зачем? ;)